# C++ Instantiating objects in another class

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Circle{
    private:
        float radius;
        float xCoord;
        float yCoord;
    public:
        Circle():radius(0),xCoord(0),yCoord(0){};
        Circle(float r, float x, float y): radius(r), xCoord(x),yCoord(y){};

        void PrintCircle(){
            cout << radius << ' ' << xCoord << ' ' << yCoord;
        }
};

class Cylinder{
    private:
        Circle circle;
        float height;
    public:
        Cylinder():height(0){};
        Cylinder(float r, float x, float y, float h):circle(r,x,y),height(h){};

        void PrintCylinder(){
            circle.PrintCircle();
            cout << ' ' << height << endl;
        }
};

int main(){
    Cylinder c1;
    c1.PrintCylinder();

    Cylinder c2(5,5,5,5);
    c2.PrintCylinder();

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0 0 0 0
5 5 5 5
```

In `Cylinder class`, I declared a `Circle` object member, which calls Circle's default constructor. `Cylinder c1` verifies this. Then in `Cylinder c2`, I use the other Circle constructor on the Circle object.

My question - does the `Circle` object in `c2` use two constructors? Why does this work? Or is this merely how object declarations within classes work?

EDIT:
I'm not asking about about member initialization lists.

Say I wanted to create a `Circle` object in `main()` using its default constructor.

```
int main(){
    Circle c;
}
```

Now look at the data members of `Cylinder` class.

```
class Cylinder{
    private:
        Circle circle; //Default constructor?
        float height;
}
```

When creating a `Cylinder` object, would `Circle circle` call its default constructor automatically? If it does then that brings me to the 'two constructors' point.

For `Cylinder c2`, that would mean its `Circle` object calls its constructors `Circle()` then `Circle(float r, float x, float y)` due to `Cylinder(float r, float x, float y, float h):circle(r,x,y),height(h){}`.

Comment: What do you mean by *"uses two constructors"*?

Comment: Are you wondering about [the constructor initializer lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711990/what-is-this-weird-colon-member-syntax-in-the-constructor)?